# Javascript calculator keeps concatenating calculation results with first number entered for next calculation

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<FORM NAME="Calculator">
<TABLE BORDER=4>
<TR>
<TD>
<input type="text"   name="Input" Size="22" value="">


<br>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one"   VALUE="1" class ="digit" >
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two"   VALUE="2" class ="digit" >
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" VALUE="3" class ="digit" >
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus"  VALUE="+" class ="operand">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four"  VALUE="4" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five"  VALUE="5" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six"   VALUE="6" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="minus" VALUE="-" class="operand">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" VALUE="7" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" VALUE="8" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine"  VALUE="9" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="times" VALUE="*" class ="operand">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" VALUE="c" class ="special">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero"  VALUE="0" class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Execute"  VALUE="=" class ="solve">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="div"   VALUE="/" class ="operand">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Quonn\Desktop\QBJS\calculatorjs.js">
</script>
</body>
```

I am building a configurable calculator but I am having some with my logic/getting it to behave exactly how i want. I have two questions.

**Question # 1:** How can I change my logic so that I can replace "evil eval"?

```
var timer;
document.onclick = function(x) {
var info = x.target;
clearTimeout(timer);
 timer= setTimeout(function(){addDigit(x);},200);
}
```

**Question #2**: How can change my logic in this function so that after a calculation result is displayed, the first number entered for the next calculation isn't just concatenated to the previous calculation's result?

```
function addDigit(x){
if (x.target.className === "digit" || x.target.className ==="operand") {
    document.Calculator.Input.value += "" + x.target.value;
}

else if (x.target.className === "solve") {
    result = eval(document.Calculator.Input.value);
    document.Calculator.Input.value = result;
}
else  {
   document.Calculator.Input.value = "";
}

}
```

Comment: why is there a timer (setTimeout)?

Comment: Because I am adding a double click function later.

Comment: You might just want to make the 'operator' buttons read the input-string via parseFloat to a floating point number, storing it in a var (or array) together with the operation you want it to do with next number. If you want to enter a full formula and not use eval, you'd need a parser/lexer to make sense of the string. Finally (to avoid disappointment), you are aware that in javascript 0.1+0.2 is NOT (exactly) 0.3?

Comment: also, do you require Parentheses `( )` to be supported in your calculator like: `6*(12+3)` ? That would really make it more difficult.. What I'm saying is, you should probably rethink your current strategy and/or look at some other javascript calculator and see how they actually do their math without eval (and with parenthesis).

Comment: If you are really serious about making sense of a string (essentially rebuilding the google calculator) you might take a look at [META II](http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/mc_tutorial.html) Quote: 'Also you will be able to move the compiler you build off these web pages and into your programming language of choice by cutting and pasting. After all a compiler is just a program that reads text and writes text or binary. ' If you look at Step 2.1 you can see what a calculator actually does.. If you understand the whole tutorial you can even build (on that site) your own programming language..

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating strings. You should have a look at [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) / [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat); watch out for the radix, otherwise JavaScript will try to guess it...